# ReadFile blocking when reading from pipe

Tags: delphi, winapi

I want to read a console program output. The problem is that ReadFile deadlocks my thread. Even when process exists still the same. I heard that you must close Write Pipe but when doing so it does not read nothing.

Here is my code:

```
var
  saSec : TSecurityAttributes;
  hRead, hWrite : THandle;
  SI : TStartupInfo;
  PI : TProcessInformation;
  Running,dwRead : DWORD;
  buf : array [0..1024] of AnsiChar;
  data : AnsiString;
begin
  saSec.nLength := sizeof(TSecurityAttributes);
  saSec.bInheritHandle := false;
  saSec.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

  if CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, @saSec, 0) then
  begin
     FillChar(SI, Sizeof(TStartupInfo), #0);
     FillChar(PI, Sizeof(TProcessInformation), #0);
     SI.hStdInput := hRead;
     SI.hStdOutput := hWrite;
     SI.hStdError := hWrite;
     SI.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
     SI.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;

     if CreateProcess(nil, PChar('openvpn' + cert), @saSec, @saSec, False, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, SI, PI) then
     begin
          data := '';
          repeat
            Running := WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, 100);
            repeat
                  FillChar(buf, sizeof(buf), #0);
                  ReadFile(hRead, buf, sizeof(buf), dwRead, nil);
                  data := data + buf;
                   if Pos('sequence completed', data) >0 then
                  begin
                    status := 1;
                    Synchronize(Sync);
                  end;
            until dwRead < sizeof(buf);

          until Running <> WAIT_TIMEOUT ;
          status := 0;
          Synchronize(Sync);
          CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
          CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
     end;
```

Comment: The problem is you need to call first PeekNamedPipe to see if data is available, to avoid blocking the thread. Example here : http://thundaxsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/12/capturing-console-output-with-delphi.html

Comment: Why are you connecting both ends of the same pipe to stdin and stdout of the same process? Why would the process want to use its own output as its input?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using overlapped I/O, `ReadFile` will block until data are available from the handle being read, or until some error condition on the handle.

You're waiting to read from a pipe that nothing will ever write to. You disabled inheritance when you created the handles, so the process you create won't receive them. Allow inheritance when you assign to `saSec.bInheritHandle`, at least prior to calling `CreatePipe`. (You can change it in preparation for `CreateProcess`, if you don't want the new process and thread handles to be inheritable by subsequent processes.) Also mind the fifth parameter of `CreateProcess`, which controls the same thing.

Raymond Chen published an [article expanding on the topic of inheriting handles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/16/10248328.aspx) a few years ago.

Comment: Assigned bInheritHandle := true same behaivour.

Comment: @opc0de: You're also passing `False` to the `bInheritHandles` argument to CreateProcess.

Comment: @HarryJohnston put True and you will see same behaivour ReadFile blocks until there is data to be read. In order to prevent blocking use PeekNamedPipe

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean - when the process exits, ReadFile() keeps blocking.  Yes, you *can* work around that by polling (i.e., PeekNamedPipe) but it isn't the best solution; polling is inefficient.  Instead, close your handle `hWrite` after calling CreateProcess().  That way, when the child exits, the write end of the pipe will be closed, and ReadFile() will exit with `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`.